# What happens if an edited question gets deleted?

Tags: discussion

We edit other's questions to improve them. Whenever an edit is approved (for my case I need approval) we get 2 reputation points. But what happens if our edited question gets deleted?

Comment: You get the reputation points immediately for the edit.  You would only lose reputation points if you had accepted an answer and it was deleted and/or the question was your own and it was deleted

Comment: @SecurityHound No.. one gets the 2 reputation points when the edit is approved. Not before. And one's reputation points are reduced again if the post is deleted (separately or along with the Question) or if one of the suggested edit approvers are deleted. No idea why you're talking about accepted answers.

Comment: @Scratte - My comment was under the assumption the edit was approved then the question was deleted

Comment: Is there a time threshold after which rep won't be deleted if the post is deleted? Or is it perpetually attached to the relevant post?

Comment: Welp, the dupe answers my question directly.